# read xml tag from a file containing single line in bat file

Tags: xml, batch-file

I have to read a particular tag from a xml file which has the whole content in a single line.
For example my employee.xml file will look something as shown below

```
<EMP><FNAME>ss</FNAME><LNAME>rr</LNAME><ID>11</ID></EMP>
```

I would like to read the value of LNAME in .bat file.

I am able to read the file if all the tags come on a separate line, but if they come in a single line then my code fails.

Can anyone please help in resolving this? also is it possible to handle both the scenarios in the same batch file?

Answer (score 1):

This uses a helper batch file called `repl`.bat from - http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855

Put `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file.

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type employee.xml ^|repl ".*<LNAME>(.*)</LNAME>.*" "$1" a ') do echo "%%a"
pause
```

Comment: any simple way without using the repl.bat

Comment: Simple?  Maybe.  Simple and reliable with data that can change?  Maybe, but usually not.  It all depends on the exact literal data and how it can change.  Batch files rely on the makeup of the data in very many cases.  You can use third party tools like SED, which will be a simple command.

Comment: The xml file will have the same structure and will always look for a particular field (LNAME in this example).

Comment: If the <LNAME></LNAME> tags are always in the same relative spot with the same number of tags before it, and none of the intermediate data contains < or > then it could be doable.  Just count the delimiters of < and > and set the token number to the field in between <LNAME> and </LNAME>.  The batch file doesn't locate the LNAME in this case, it just counts the tokens where it should be, as it relies on the makeup of the data.  The `repl` bat is more robust.

Comment: +1, You probably should add the A option so that only Altered lines are printed.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (q19138159.txt) DO SET line=%%i
:loop
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=<>" %%i IN ("%line%") DO SET line=%%j&IF /i NOT "%%i"=="lname" GOTO loop
FOR /f "tokens=1delims=<>" %%i IN ("%line%") DO SET line=%%i
ECHO lname=%line%=
GOTO :EOF
```

where q19138159.txt is the file containing your XML line.

---

For large files - with support from SED

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN (
 'sed s#.*\x3cLName\x3e\(.*\^)\x3c/LName\x3e.*#\1# q19138159.txt'
 ) DO ECHO %%i

GOTO :eof
```

`GNUSED` will process a file that contains `<LName>something or other</LName>` to extract the `something or other`.

The processing command is

```
 
s substitute  
# a delimiter  
.* Any number of any characters   
\x3c   
\( sed instruction : save...  
.* any number of any characters  
\^) End of thing-to-be-saved; `)` escaped by `^` to not-close the `IN`  
\x3c   
.* any number of any characters  
# delimiter between substitute-for-string and substitute-with string  
\1 retrieve thing #1 saved  
# end of substitute-with string
```

Google for `GNUSED`.

Comment: That's effective and dynamic.

Comment: This works for the OP's example. But it may fail if the XML content exceeds ~8k bytes.

Comment: Thats true. I tested with a file that was about 5MB and this code does not work. Is it possible to change the logic for big files?

Comment: The maximum stringlength that batch can assign is 8191-(length of variablename) [or perhaps 8190 - lovn]. Naturally, if some other language is invoked, or a 3rd party tool that is designed for the job (like SED or AWK) then this limit can be worked-around. There is a canyon between the 57-character example posted and a 5MB record. There are also other problems with this approach - like `lname` as a data item, not a token.  It's a continuing problem in Computer Science, like in other fields. Virtually any solution has its limits.

Comment: The xml has the same structure but the sometimes the value of one of the xml tag can be huge making it go over 8kb. But still the LName tag will always reamin at the same place. Is it not possible to alter the code to read ust the LName and ignore reading the whole file?

Comment: Possibly - if the xml has the target endtag in the first 8190 characters, otherwise you need support from some other toolset. I've amended the code to use SED. I tested on a 32K file with the target in the middle. No idea whether it'd work for an 8M file though...might depend on the SED version you choose.

Comment: @user2593173: you COULD replace `<LNAME>` and `</LNAME>` with a char not used elsewhere and use this char as a token. This will give you exactly three tokens, where the second one is what you are looking for. (Not that **I** would rely on this - see other comments).